# How resize Tab control programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabcontrol

I want programmatically resize tab Control on my winform.

```
tabCtrl.Size.Width = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);
tabCtrl.Size.Height= Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown2.Value);
```

But I get error:

> **Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Size' because it is not a variable**

Any idea how can I resize Tab control programmatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this. Note the `(int)` cast because `NummericUpdown.Value` is a `decimal` value.

```
tabCtrl.Size = new Size((int)numericUpDown1.Value, (int)numericUpDown2.Value);
```